# Check chroma subsampling of image or video

Tags: python, image, video, image-compression

After doing some image manipulation, I'd like to save the new images/videos with the same quality settings as the source.  If the source is JPEG, Pillow provides a JpegImagePlugin.get_sampling method.  Is there a way to determine what subsampling other image/video files are using?